# Golang - google/protobuf/Empty.proto: File not found

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

```
syntax = "proto3";

package model;

import "google/protobuf/Empty.proto";

message User {
    string id = 1;
    string name  = 2;
    string email = 3;
    string alamat = 4;
    string password = 5;
}

message UserList {
    repeated User list = 1;
}

message userId {
    string id = 1; 
}

message UserUpdate {
    string id = 1;
    User user = 2;
}

service Users {
    rpc getUserList(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (UserList) {}
    rpc getUserById(userId) returns (User) {}
    rpc inserUser(User) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
    rpc updateUser(UserUpdate) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {} 
    rpc deleteUser(userId) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}  
}
```

above is my proto file. I get error google/protobuf/Empty.proto: File not found.
when trying to compile the proto file above. can someone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the correct import is `import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";`

second, for generating a proto file run this code:

```
protoc --proto_path={proto_directory_address} --proto_path={proto_directory_name} --go-grpc_out={generated_directory_path} --go_out={generated_directory_path} {proto_directory_address}/{proto_file_name}.proto
```

Comment: I believe it's `--go_grpc_out` with an underscore, not `--go-grpc_out`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because I had not installed the protoc correctly

For successful installation do these steps:

1. Download latest version from here https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases
2. Extract in your computer
3. move bin/protoc to /usr/local/bin

```
sudo mv {downloaded_directory}/bin/protoc /usr/local/bin
```

4. move include folder to /usr/local

```
sudo mv {downloaded_directory}/include /usr/local
```

Comment: I had to add `--proto_path=/usr/local/include/:.` otherwise it wouldn't see the path at all. The `:.` is so it looks in the current dir also, otherwise it won't see your proto file

Comment: @MikeKulls I just import "google/protobuf/empty.proto" to the proto file

Answer (score 0):

hi there / i had the same issue for a long time ..  this process worked for me i hope it dose for you too :
navigate to  this directory using your cmd(command line) :

> cd .local/include

this directory normally should contain some folder named "google" copy this folder and paste it to this directory :

> /usr/local/include

and now try the protoc engine again to generate your project and if the error still exists then try the rest of process :

navigate to that specific directory and check if its been copied or not . if it is then try to navigate to the folder from where you are (which it should be /usr/local/include) if the error says you have no permission to get in the folder
use this command to get the permission

> $ sudo chmod o+r -R ./google

and then try to get permission to get in protobuf folder in the same directory using above command again
when its all done . check the protoc generator again /// hope works for you because it dose for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

import public "google/protobuf/empty.proto";